# How to delete content from all files within a given folder preserving the names?

Tags: shell

I want to delete content from every file within a folder (Which includes files in all the sub folders and sub-sub-folders etc.) What is the best possible way to do the same?

Alternatively, Is there a way to copy only the file names (Empty files) and structure from a given folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find folder/to/frob -type f -exec sh -c '> "{}"' \;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you. Can you please explain this a bit?

Comment: `find` finds the files. `sh -c` runs a shell command you pass to it. Redirecting to a file without a source truncates it.